# I don't understand how the $(this) jQuery object works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning how jquery works and so far it's going good, but I'm stuck at the `$(this)` object. And here is the part of the code that I don't understand well.

```
$(".photos").on("mouseenter", "li", function(){

$(this).closest(".photos").find("span").slideToggle();


});
```

The `$(this)` is referring to the elements with the class photos( $(".photos") ) or to the li(s) which are inside at the elements with the class photos?

Comment: $(this) refers to its parent in functiin twich has  $(".photos") and has been selected. It simply refers to an elemnt that brought you to the function

Comment: [Related documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler): *When jQuery calls a handler, **the `this` keyword is a reference to the element** where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and **for delegated events this is an element matching `selector`**. [...]*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the event handler, `this` is the `li` that that mouse has moved into so `$(this)` is just that single element.

Because it is a *delegated event handler*, the "li" filter is applied to all `mouseenter` events that bubble up to the .photos element. It then applies the function/handler to *each matching element that caused the event* (which will be the single `LI` under the mouse).